# TDD: why, how and real world test driven code

Tags: tdd

First, Please bear with me with all my questions. I have never used TDD before but more and more I come to realize that I should. I have read a lot of posts and how to guides on TDD but some things are still not clear. Most example used for demonstration are either math calculation or some other simple operations. I also started reading Roy Osherove's book about TDD. Here are some questions I have:

If you have an object in your solution, for instance an Account class, what is the benefit of testing setting a property on it, for example an account name, then you Assert that whatever you set is right. Would this ever fail?

Another example, an account balance, you create an object with balance 300 then you  assert that the balance is actually 300. How would that ever fail? What would I be testing here? I can see testing a subtraction operation with different input parameters would be more of a good test.

What should I actually test my objects for? methods or properties? sometime you also have objects as service in an infrastructure layer. In the case of methods, if you have a three tier app and the business layer is calling the data layer for some data. What gets tested in that case? the parameters? the data object not being null? what about in the case of services?

Then on to my question regarding real life project, if you have a green project and you want to start it with TDD. What do you start with first? do you divide your project into features then tdd each one or do you actually pick arbitrarily and you go from there.

For example, I have a new project and it requires a login capability. Do I start with creating User tests or Account tests or Login tests. Which one I start with first? What do I test in that class first?

Let's say I decide to create a User class that has a username and password and some other properties. I'm supposed to create the test first, fix all build error, run the test for it to fail then fix again to get a green light then refactor. So what are the first tests I should create on that class? For example, is it:

- Username_Length_Greater_Than_6
- Username_Length_Less_Than_12
- Password_Complexity

If you assert that length is greater than 6, how is that testing the code? do we test that we throw an error if it's less than 6?

I am sorry if I was repetitive with my questions. I'm just trying to get started with TDD and I have not been able to have a mindset change. Thank you and hopefully someone can help me determine what am I missing here. By the way, does anyone know of any discussion groups or chats regarding TDD that I can join?

Comment: testdrivendevelopment yahoogroup has some very wise and helpful members.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at low-level BDD. [This post by Dan North](http://dannorth.net/introducing-bdd/) introduces it quite well.

Rather than testing properties, think about the behavior you're looking for. For instance:

```
Account Behavior:
    should allow a user to choose the account name
    should allow funds to be added to the account

User Registration Behavior:
    should ensure that all usernames are between 6 and 12 characters
    should ask the password checker if the password is complex enough <-- you'd use a mock here
```

These would then become tests for each class, with the "should" becoming the test name. Each test is an example of how the class can be used valuably. Instead of testing methods and properties, you're showing someone else (or your future self) why the class is valuable and how to change it safely.

We also do something in BDD called "outside-in". So start with the GUI (or normally the controller / presenter, since we don't often unit-test the GUI).

You already know how the GUI will use the controller. Now write an example of that. You'll probably have more than one aspect of behavior, so write more examples until the controller works. The controller will have a number of collaborating classes that you haven't written yet, so mock those out - just dependency inject them via an interface. You can write them later.

When you've finished with the controller, replace the next thing you've mocked out in the real system by real code, and test-drive that. Oh, and don't bother mocking out domain objects (like Account) - it'll be a pain in the neck - but do inject any complex behavior into them and mock that out instead.

This way, you're always writing the interface that you wish you had - something that's easy to use - for every class. You're describing the behavior of that class and providing some examples of how to use it. You're making it safe and easy to change, and the appropriate design will emerge (feel free to be guided by patterns, thoughtful common sense and experience).

BTW, with Login, I tend to work out what the user wants to log in *for*, then code that first. Add Login later - it's usually not very risky and doesn't change much once it's written, so you may not even need to unit-test it. Up to you.

Answer (score 3):

1. Test until fear is replaced by boredom. Property accessors and constructors are high cost to benefit to write tests against. I usually test them indirectly as part of some other (higher) test.
2. For a new project, I'd recommend looking at ATDD. Find a user-story that you want to pick first (based on user value). Write an acceptance test that should pass when the user story is done. Now drill down into the types that you'd need to get the AT to pass -- using TDD. The acceptance test will tell you which objects and what behaviors are required. You then implement them one at a time using TDD. When all your tests (incl your acc. test) pass - you pick up the next user story and repeat.

Let's say you pick 'Create user' as your first story. Then you write examples of how that should work. Turn them into automated acceptance tests.
create valid user -> account should be created
create invalid user ( diff combinations that show what is invalid ) -> account shouldn't be created, helpful error shown to the user

AccountsVM.CreateUser(username, password)
AccountsVM.HasUser(username)
AccountsVM.ErrorMessage

The test would show that you need the above. You then go test-drive them them out.

Answer (score 2):

Don't test what is too simple to break.

- getters and setters are too simple to be broken, so said, the code is so simple that an error can not happen.
- you test the public methods and assert the response is as expected. If the method return void you have to test "collateral consequences" (sometimes is not easy, eg to test a email was sent). When this happens you can use mocks to test not the response but how the method executes (you ask the mockk if the Class Under Test called him the desired way)

I start doing Katas to learn the basics: JUnit and TestNG; then  Harmcrest; then read EasyMock or Mockito documentation.

Look for katas at github, or here
http://codekata.pragprog.com
http://codingdojo.org/

The first test should be the easiest one! Maybe one that just force you to create the CUT (class under test)

But again, try katas!

http://codingdojo.org/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?KataFizzBuzz